# Can anyone confirm whether MacRuby framework shipped with Lion?

Tags: macos, development, xcode

Somewhere I read that Apple wants to include macruby framework in OS X Lion.

Did they include it?

Comment: Would you mind if I edited this to remove the opinion / subjective parts? We can't really know if you should or shouldn't do anything - feel free to proclaim to the world that you want to run MacRuby on Lion and would appreciate any tips until the MacRuby website publishes their lion support article.

Comment: Ok. I want to know need I am to install macruby, or Apple, as promised, (did they promised?) already installed it with Lion.

Comment: I took a stab at editing it down - I hope you approve and can't wait to see what people do with the framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macruby is there as a private framework, and you can call it as such using code. For more elaboration, you should ask your question again on Stackoverflow.

http://redwoodapp.posterous.com/macruby-for-the-desktop-six-reasons

Answer (score 0):

Here are instructions on how to install MacRuby

http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/InstallingMacRuby